# What are the equivalent functions of fmincon with 'trust-region-reflective' algorithm and fminsearchbnd in R?

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to reproduce the following matlab functions in R. I need to find the closest approximations of fmincon and fminsearchbnd in R.

```
if license('test','optimization_toolbox')
    % IF OPTIMIZATION TOOLBOX IS PRESENT, AN ANALYTICAL GRADIENT BASED
    % MINIMIZATION APPROACH IS USED (trust-region-reflective)
    if(exist('optimoptions', 'file'))
      options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','trust-region-reflective','Display','off','GradObj','on','MaxIter',2000,...
                           'MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-8,'TolX',1e-8);
    else
      options = optimset('Algorithm','trust-region-reflective','Display','off','GradObj','on','MaxIter',2000,...
                           'MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-8,'TolX',1e-8);  
    end
    [xfit1,fval1] = fmincon(FUN_MIN_GRAD_PARAMETRIZED,x0,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);
  end
    % WE also USE A CONSTRAINED VERSION OF FREELY AVAILABLE fminsearch 
    % (THIS USES DERIFVATIVE FREE SIMPLEX ALGORITHM)
    [xfit2,fval2] =  fminsearchbnd(FUN_MIN_GRAD_PARAMETRIZED,x0,LB,UB,optimset(...
                     'MaxIter',2000,'MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-8,'TolX',1e-8));
```

The *pracma* package provides fmincon equivalence but with the  Squential
Quadratic Programming (SQP) approach.

Are there any equivalent functions of fmincon with trust-region-reflective algorithm and fminsearchbnd in R?

Comment: ```minqa::bobyqa``` is a trust-region-based optimizer. It uses quadratic approximation though.

Comment: Take a look at the CRAN task view https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html for overview of packages and methods.  My opinion - there are a large number of algorithms for nonlinear optimization and it may not be necessary to find the same exact method.  It's probably more important to find a method that gives a good result with good performance.